# Clone of laptop HDD to SSD fails

Tags: windows-7, ssd, clone

I recently decided to update my wifes old Compaq laptop by adding more memory, which was very easy and now want to replace the clunky old HDD with a Crucial BX500 SSD.

Using the Crucial version of the cloning software it reported complete but the finished SSD didn't boot because apparently there was no operating system on it!

I wiped the SSD and cloned it again and this time the partitions are all there, but they are, according to Windows Disk management, all empty! I found this out by taking the SSD and plugging it into the USB port on my Windows 10 PC.

Now I'm confused! Any suggestions please?

Thank you!

Comment: How big is your wife's HDD?

Comment: Boot from a Windows installer DVD/USB-stick and execute the boot repair function. Also check your system BIOS if the SSD is enabled for boot and is the first in the boot device list.

Comment: My wife's HDD is only 250GB so there should be plenty of space on the new SSD.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the software that ships with the Crucial drives, but if you inspected the drive on another computer after cloning and there was no data it suggests something is wrong with the Crucial software.  You don't have bitlocker encryption enabled on the source drive you are trying to upgrade do you?  That could be interfering. Check Windows settings for bitlocker and then turn it off and try again.

Alternately, try another piece of software.  Macrium Reflect has a free version as well as AOMEI Standard.  I have personally used Macrium Reflect free version on multiple HDD to SSD conversions even when there were complicated partition setups that included recovery partitions and it always worked for me.